# Why am I getting different font sizes when displaying my page in chrome android using input tag

Tags: android, html, css, forms, input

Why is it the chrome browser for android is displaying text within the 'form' tag in a different font size to the text outside it. I've tried giving all text the same font size and font in CSS but it doesn't seem to make a difference.

If you run the snippet code below you won't see the effect. I think the only way to view this problem is on an android phone. I've put the page online [here](http://www.bespoke-wooden-windows.co.uk/bigFont.html).     Here is the [view through Chrome developer tools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/42Rwe.jpg).
It seems that this error does not occur when there are less than 240 characters before the form tag starts. If you use more than 240 characters the error occurs. Could this be a bug?

```css
span.time1 {
 font-size : 18px;
 font-family : "Times New Roman",Times,serif; 
}
form.time2 {
 font-size : 18px;
 font-family : "Times New Roman",Times,serif;  
}
```

```html
<Span class = "time1">The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.The quick brown fox jumped overThe quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.The quick brown fox jumped overc</Span>
<form class = "time2">
  First name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="firstname">
</form>
```

What could be going wrong, and how do I fix it?

Comment: where is your css and in android is your browser set to view above 100%?

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: mlegg, I've added the CSS. I've checked the setting in chrome for android but there is nothing that lets me alter the view to above 100%. This problem also occurs in the 'internet' browser for android.

Comment: Try setting the attributes you want for `input` instead of `form`

Comment: the INPUT tag has it's own browser-defaults. You can hook up your mobile device to your PC and use google:chrome-DeveloperTools on it for the mobile device instance. Not my favourite HowTo, but best I found ATM: http://devtoolsecrets.com/secret/mobile-using-developer-tools-on-android.html ... ahh: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/debug/remote-debugging/remote-debugging

Comment: Neither of my android devices shows a difference in font size there. By the way, @flowtron has a point: you're not talking about the size of the text in the input?

Comment: @flowtron I've 'inspected' my device through chrome by hooking it up to my PC.The problem exits through this method as well. How would the 'device instance' help?

Comment: @mrlister I'm viewing it through a samsung S5 mobile phone. When viewing the code through chrome the font size of the text in the input field is the same as the 'first name:' text,   both of which are different font sizes to the 'the quick brown fox.....' text. My S5 phone is the only device that I seen this happen to.

Comment: See screen sample in chrome developer tools here  http://i.stack.imgur.com/42Rwe.jpg

Comment: I bet you've got a "text-zoom" setting other than 100% .. I've banged my head against that a couple of times before. It totally borks font-size CSS values. :-(

Comment: @flowtron, In the settings for chrome on my S5 phone my 'text scaling' is set at 100% and the 'Force enable zoom' box isn't ticked. I've also tested my problem on another phone, S5 mini, and the same thing happens. So the problem can't be isolated to my phone.

Comment: @JamesCurrie Mmmh. Try setting font-size in % - 18px is 112.5% of 16px which is a browser-default classic. And wrap the "label" (First name:) in a span class=time1 too.

Comment: @flowtron I tried your suggestion and still no joy. :(

Comment: try this: https://jsfiddle.net/grk8xwr9/

Comment: @flowtron I've tried it and still no joy.

Comment: It seems that this error does not occur when there are less than 240 characters before form tag starts. If you use more than 240 characters the error occurs. Could this be a bug?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the solution! Put this line into the Head.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1">
```

Comment: Thank you, I was having this problem too

Answer (score 0):

```
input {
font-size : 18px;
font-family : "Times New Roman",Times,serif;        
   }
```

Try this

Answer (score 0):

The font style for your form doesn't necessarily apply to the form field(s), such as `input`.  You can specify that `input` fields should use the same fonts, like this:

```css
span.time1, form.time2, form.time2 > input, form.time2 > label, form.time2 > select {
  font-size : 18px;
  font-family : "Times New Roman",Times,serif;
}
```

```html
<Span class = "time1">The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.The quick brown fox jumped overThe quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.The quick brown fox jumped overc</Span>
<form class = "time2">
  <label for="firstname">First name:</label><br>
  <input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname">
</form>
```

This code also includes font support for `label` and `select` fields, as an example.  Note the use of the `label` in the HTML snippet.  You may also choose to include support for additional form elements, such as buttons.

Comment: Thanks but your solution hasn't resolved the problem. Please see my problem here http://i.stack.imgur.com/42Rwe.jpg

Answer (score 0):

James Currie wrote:

> `<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1">`

Thanks, James - the "viewport" meta tag sorted out my problem.  However, the resulting text ends up by being the same size as the smallest there was without the meta tag - but at least that can be dealt with in css if needed (but ensure doing so doesn't mess up presentation on a desktop).

This only manifests itself in Android Chrome - not Chrome on a desktop or any variant of Firefox.  So it really does seem Google is trying to force use of this meta tag everywhere - even though it is only the tiny screens on phones that are sometimes illegible without it.  Tablets don't need it for legibility.

There is another Android Chrome problem with tables: spacing of cells with different coloured backgrounds.  Normally `padding-top:0.5em;` would do the trick, but `padding` takes on the cell's background colour, which was not what I wanted.  So I used `border-top:0.5em solid white;` to get the spacing I required.  (The example colour, white, should be the same as your table's background colour - you can't use `transparent` because the cell background colour would show through (ie. it would have the same effect as `padding`).  Yes - I could have used `border-spacing`, but that applies to the whole table: I only wanted it to apply to specific rows.  All hunky-dory as I originally thought - the code below rendered exactly what I wanted on my desktop:

```
<td style="background-color:red; color:white; border-top:0.5em solid white;">RED</td>
```

.. which is the word RED in white text on a red background with a white separator above it.  However, in Android Chrome, there was an annoying 1 pixel wide border round my border block, which was the cell's background colour - so only visible if the cell background is a strong colour.  This annoyance disappears when the meta tag is in place.